# user defined struct can't be passed through tid.send

Tags: multithreading, d

I have created a mutlithreaded simulator that relies heavily on the native message passing between threads (don't go telling me to go single threaded it's for my thesis on D and I need to get this to work)

after a very durty kludge involving a lot of casts of objects to and from `shared`. which prolly had some ugly race condition bugs. I decided to create an opaque type that represents an object that can receive messages that should be able to be passed around without all that casting...

no such luck

```
struct OpaqueFaseSim{
    Tid tid;
    void send(...){...}
}

void foo(){
Tid tid;
long time;
    OpaqueFaseSim ofs;
    //...
    tid.send(ofs,time);//Error: static assert  "Aliases to mutable thread-local data not allowed."
}
```

why can I pass a Tid around but not a struct containing *only* a Tid?

and how can I fix this

Comment: As a guess from reading the error message: You might try adding an immutable in there somewhere.

Comment: adding immutable to Tid means I can't send messages to it kinda defeats the purpose of having this structure (std.concurrency.send doesn't accept immutable Tid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because Tid has a MessageBox field which is a class type.

You can type OpaqueFaseSim's tid field as shared or ___gshared and it will work:

```
struct OpaqueFaseSim{
    Bar bar;
    shared Tid tid;
    // __gshared Tid tid;
}
```

Comment: yeah I dove into the lib sources not long after I asked this question and submitted a [bugfix](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=4957) for it and in my project I now use a shared Tid and cast back to non shared when sending (another weird behavior TBH)